# How do I implement error blocking and keep other menus available in a UMI3.x project?

Tags: umi

When I used the umiJS framework, I found that once the page reported an error, clicking on any menu page did not have any reaction. At this time, the only thing you can do is refresh the page, if the error is the current page, you can only switch to another page after refresh, and then re-perform page interaction.

I tried error blocking, but error blocking only shows the preset error UI interface, click the menu bar is still not available, that is, can not jump, although the address bar has changed, but the page still shows the error page.
I hope that although the page error is reported, it only affects the current page, and will not affect other pages, and the cut menu can still access other pages.

Comment: Please copy and include the text of your error. Please also include some of your code, if able.